# Does Firebase cloud messaging push-notification have field "contentAvailable" for IOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

[Firebase Cloud Messaging config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EPNB.png)

- I have a problem that when I push notification using API with field "contentAvailable" : true, when in background (IOS) I can get data. When I push notification using Firebase Cloud messaging, there is no "contentAvailable" field for me to set up for IOS. Can anyone explain problem to me ?
- I need to get "badge" when I am in background mode (IOS) to increase badge when I received message from Firebase.
  Anyone have any ideas?about this issue ?

Comment: You would normally send "real" FCM messages using the firebase apis, not the console.  When you use the API you can provide badge and content-available elements.

Comment: @Paulw11, Can I ask if I use firebase console to push notification. Is there a way for iOS to increase the number of badges in the background mode? When I push notification with value "content-available" on apis it callback "onbackgroundmessage" .

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the `contentAvailable` or rather `content_available` field is also available for iOS. You can just add the field to your server request amongst other fields like for example `badge`.

To give an example and a brief overview for possible fields in your APNS payload out of the Python FCM Admin SDK look below (the `contentAvailable` field is also available in other SDKs):

[image: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.messaging]
(Taken from official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.messaging))

With the fields you can configure your badges and their behavior.

There are also for example Android specific parameters.